# matplotlib funcAnimation growing lines with static ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib in my python script, the script is used to make some connection tests and plot them in a graph.
The animate function gets its data from other function that performs the connection tests.

I want that the graph x axis will show all hours in format of 00:00, 01:00 ... 23:00, and the animate function will put every point in the correct time spot but i haven't managed to to do it in any way.
in the image i attached i set the x axis ticks with plt.xticks([]), but as the lines grew the axis just scrolled right.
the code sample is not working! its only the animate function i don't want to attach the whole code because it's irrelevant.

animate function get's args from a generator that's first perform the tests and than yield the values, first its yield google and then facebook, master_dict is a dictionary with all the test results so its take the values for the plot from it.
graph_list is a list of 2 2d numpy arrays that contains the points of the plots.
x_val is string of datetime formatted as "%H:%M"%S", y_val is float value of the test

```
def animate(args):

    url = args[0]
    master_dict = args[1]

    plot_dict = master_dict[url]
    url_id = 1 if 'google' in url else 0

    x_val = plot_dict[TIME]
    y_val = plot_dict[BYTE]

    point = np.array([[x_val, y_val]])

    graph_list[url_id] = np.append(graph_list[url_id], point, axis=0)
    x, y = graph_list[url_id].T
    y = y.astype(np.float)
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate(rotation=60)

    return plt.plot(x, y, color=('g' if url_id else 'r'), linewidth=2)
```

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OBId.png)

Comment: I know you think the rest of the code is irrelevant, but without knowing the kind of data you are trying to plot, I don't think anybody will be able to debug your code. The idea behind a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is to reduce your code to the bare minimum that somebody can copy/paste to identify what's wrong

Comment: That being said, I'm pretty sure (at least part of) your problem is that your x-coordinates are strings.